# PommBundle Multi-insert

Tags: symfony, pomm

I would like to create a complex query with pommbundle for insert multi line in single query it's possible? can you give me a exemple?

```
insert into table values (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1);
```

Exemple :
Actualy i make that :

```
 foreach($value['finition'] as $keyFinition => $valueFinition) {
    $lot_parametre = $connecteur->getModel(LotparametreModel::class)
                                ->createAndSave(['Lot' => $lot->get('ID'),
                                                 'Parametre'    =>$keyFinition, 
                                                 'Valeur'       => $valueFinition,
                                                 'Niveau'       => 2
                                                                ]);
                }
```

And i want a solution most fastly

I have a solution :
In controller :

```
 $prepare = "";
            $valeur = array();
            if($value['parametre'] && is_array($value['parametre'])) {
                foreach($value['parametre'] as $keyParam => $valueParam) {
                    //TYPAGE PARAMETRE
                    $prepare .= "($*::integer, $*::integer, $*::integer, $*::integer),";
                    $valeur[] = $lot->get('ID');
                    $valeur[] = $keyParam;
                    $valeur[] = $valueParam;
                    $valeur[] = 1;
                }
            }

            //LOT PARAMETRE 2
            if($value['finition'] && is_array($value['finition'])) {
                foreach($value['finition'] as $keyFinition => $valueFinition) {
                    //TYPAGE PARAMETRE
                    $prepare .= "($*::integer, $*::integer, $*::integer, $*::integer),";
                    $valeur[] = $lot->get('ID');
                    $valeur[] = $keyFinition;
                    $valeur[] = $valueFinition;
                    $valeur[] = 2;
                }
            }
            //INSERTION DES PARAMETRES
            if($prepare && $valeur) {
             $lot_parametre = $connecteur->getModel(LotparametreModel::class)
                                         ->insertMulti(\rtrim($prepare,','),$valeur);
            }
```

/*MODEL*/
Lotparametremodel.php

```
 public function insertMulti($prepare, $valeur)
{

    $sql = "
        insert into {lot_parametre} 
        (\"Lot\", \"Parametre\", \"Valeur\", \"Niveau\")
        values 
        {prepare}
    ";



    $sql = strtr(
        $sql,
        [
            '{lot_parametre}'    => $this->structure->getRelation(),
            '{prepare}'          => $prepare
        ]
    );

  return $this->query($sql,$valeur);
}
```

Comment: Are there simple values you want to insert or do you need an entity based solution?

Comment: If it's possible i would like a solution with entity. I edit my post.
But if you have a solution with simple values and returning just ID it's ok